# scope in javascript (why at the scope of $.post() method array is local?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
externalCSSContents = [];

function getExternalCSSContents(){
        href = document.styleSheets[0].href;
        $.post(href, function(result){
            externalCSSContents.push(result);
            alert(externalCSSContents.length); // 1
        });
}

getExternalCSSContents();
alert(externalCSSContents.length); // 0
```

Can someone please explain to me why at the scope of $.post() method array externalCSSContents is local?

Comment: there should be a prize for the 1,000,000th person to ask an "ajax is asynchronous" question :D

Comment: @jbabey that was back in 1807 .... we are near 1,000,000,000,000,000,000

Comment: Check if your post is successful. According to query docs, the callback is being triggered only on success : " callback function that is executed if the request succeeds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the ajax request has not finished executing and you are alerting the contents of the array.

You could do this instead.

```
function getExternalCSSContents(){
    href = document.styleSheets[0].href;
    return  $.post(href, function(result){ externalCSSContents.push(result); });
}

$.when( getExternalCSSContents() ).then(function(){ 
        alert(externalCSSContents.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is asynchronous the post callback is executed after the alert

(i've typed the work 'asynchronous' so many times on here today I now know how to spell it)

Answer (score 1):

This is because asynchronous request. This is how AJAX works. Read more about ajax on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for example